# Prove an identity of the Lie derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-algebras, lie-derivative

I'm trying to prove this identity:

For any vector fields $X,Y$ and any tensor field $T$,

$\mathcal{L}_{[X,Y]} T=\mathcal{L}_X \mathcal{L}_Y T-\mathcal{L}_Y\mathcal{L}_X T$

I have seen some books proving the case where $T$ is a vector field, how can I show this is true for a tensor field $T$? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is your definition of the Lie derivative?

Comment: I use the definition in terms of the flows : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_derivative#The_Lie_derivative_of_a_tensor_field

Comment: It would probably be easier to show that the flow definition implies the algebraic definition given in the wikipedia article and then prove the result using the algebraic formula. @Didier's suggestion is along this line.

Comment: Yes, @Deane is right: my answer could be summarized as "show that the flow definition implies to the algebraic one"

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea to show the result:

- show that the Lie derivative commutes with the exterior differential (for example, show the Cartan's magic formula)
- show that if $A$ and $B$ are two tensors, then $\mathcal{L}_X(A\otimes B) = \mathcal{L}_XA \otimes B + A \otimes \mathcal{L}_X B$
- show that what you want to prove is true on vector fields and on $1$-forms. For $1$-forms, here is a hint: locally, they are all of the form $f \mathrm{d}g$, thus you can use the commutation of the Lie derivative and the exterior differential
- conclude using the fact that every tensor is locally a linear combination of simple tensors